# Calculation in virtual field not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to calculate distance between two geographical locations. one location is entered by user.

User entered location is calculated by model and is stored in the variable.

```
$ulatitude=$userLocation['Location']['latitude'];
$ulongitude=$userLocation['Location']['longitude'];
```

I have used below code to calculate the distance.

```
$this->User->virtualFields['lowestDistance'] = 'round(3959 * acos(cos(radians($ulatitude)) * cos(radians(Profile.latitude )) * cos(radians(Profile.longitude) - radians($ulongitude)) + sin(radians($ulatitude)) * sin(radians(Profile.latitude)))) ';
                $order = "User.lowestDistance";

                $options = array(               
                                'fields' => '
                                User.*, Profile.*,
                                      round(3959 * acos(cos(radians($ulatitude)) * cos(radians(Profile.latitude )) * cos(radians(Profile.longitude) - radians($ulongitude)) + sin(radians($ulatitude)) * sin(radians(Profile.latitude))))  AS lowestDistance,
                                      ',

                                'order' => array($order =>'asc'),
                            );
```

Above code throws error :   unknown column $ulatitude.

Is there any other way of doing this ?

Comment: I hope that you validate/sanitize the `$ulatitude/ulongitude` values somewhere? Otherwise you've just created an SQL injection vulnerability!

Answer (score 1):

### Single quotes are not interpreted

Consider:

```
<?php

$foo = "A VARIABLE";

echo 'foo is $foo' . "\n";
echo "foo is $foo" . "\n";
```

This would output:

```
-> php example.php
foo is $foo
foo is A VARIABLE
```

In the question everything is in single quotes, they are literal strings.

### Fields should be an array

Also note that this:

```
'fields' => 'User.*, Profile.*, ...
```

Is normally an array, which makes more sense when there's multiple values:

```
'fields' => [
    'User.*', 
    'Profile.*', 
    ...
]
```

But since you're declaring all fields plus a virtual field, it'd be included in a find call anyway - just remove the fields from the find parameters:

```
$this->User->virtualFields['lowestDistance'] = "round(...";
$options = [
    //'fields' => [], Not necessary
    'order' => [$order =>'asc']
];
$withLowestDistance = $this->User->find('all', $options);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you've done, the question still does not have an accepted answer. See [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: i don't have earned that much of reputation. that is why it is not showing

Comment: There is no reputation required to accept an answer to your own question, the only thing required is to click on a tick mark.